# Rows are not being added to the Oracle DB table column using Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I wrote a Python script for adding information to the "CLIENT_NUMBER" column, but it doesn't work, meaning it doesn't add the numbers to the column. Why could this be, if when running the SQL script in DBeaver everything is added?

```
def insert_client_numbers(connection, cursor, table_name):
    client_numbers = client_numbers_text.get("1.0", tk.END).strip()

    if not client_numbers:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter client numbers")
        return

    client_numbers = client_numbers.split('\n')

    # Create a string with comma-separated values
    client_numbers_str = ",".join(["'{}'".format(client_number) for client_number in client_numbers])

    # Use sys.odcivarchar2list for multiple insertion
    insert_statement = f"""
    INSERT INTO {table_name} (CLIENT_NUMBER)
    SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('{client_numbers_str}'))
    """

    try:
        cursor.execute(insert_statement)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to add client numbers to the table: {str(e)}")
        return

    # Check that the rows have been added
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Convert the list of tuples to a string with the required formatting
    rows_formatted = ",\n".join([f"('{row[0]}')" for row in rows])
    print(f"Current rows in the table {table_name}:\n{rows_formatted}")  # Debug message

    messagebox.showinfo("Information", f"{len(client_numbers)} client numbers successfully added to the table {table_name}")
```

I use the following method for filling rows:

```
INSERT INTO virtual_magican (CLIENT_NUMBER)
SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('5533380','5651238', '75405689','9375691'));
```

In the Python script, I removed the semicolon, but it is still unsuccessful. There are no errors, and the message appears:
"Information", f"{len(client_numbers)} clients added to the {table_name} table"
The problem is in the Python script itself. I don't understand why.
The database itself is operational, everything connects without any problems. Any ideas what the problem might be and what needs to be fixed?

I'm using an Oracle database.

I've tried many things, but nothing has helped :(

Comment: Hi check if the table is having an Constraints which  is not being satisfied, like Unique, Not Null

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks if someone enters the client number `',(SELECT password_hash FROM secret_table WHERE username = 'admin'),'` You should never build queries using string concatenation (or template strings); instead use parameterised queries and bind variable wherever you can or sanitise your user input if you cannot.

Comment: Start with a simpler INSERT statement which doesn't do a SELECT.  Do some debugging.  Use bind variables: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html

Answer (score 0):

simply try:

```
INSERT INTO virtual_magican (CLIENT_NUMBER)
SELECT column_value 
FROM sys.odcivarchar2list('5533380','5651238', 
  '75405689','9375691');
```

Applying table function to sys.odcivarchar2list doesn't make sense to me for sys.odcivarchar2list is already returning a table.